# Storing consecutive values from a function to a vector?

Tags: r, function, loops, vector

I've been messing around learning functions to calculate homework answers (in this case the present value of money) and I've run into a bit of an issue.

Here's the code:

```
pv <- function(x,y,z) {
   list2 <- 0
   ans <- 0
   for(t in z){
     fv <- x
     d <- y
     rate <- (1+d)^t
     ans[t] <- fv/rate
   }
   return(ans)
 }
```

To calculate present value I want to apply the function to one value for a range of years (z=1:10, say) and have the value for each year stored in a vector.  What I have works, but this strategy breaks down in other applications.  For example, when I want to input a vector of values (I have another function where I run the `ans` vector through a function) for a range of years I have trouble getting back a usable vector.

Comment: Does what you have work for a single input value of `x`? You can use `sapply` to utilize the function with a vector of values: `sapply(vectorOfValues,pv )`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  When I use sapply and store the values to a vector will they be in order?  I've been confused about the usage of sapply.

Comment: Yes they will be. `sapply` is used to plug each element of a vector into a function and return the result. The 's' stands for simplify apply. However,  `sapply` is not correct here, since your function has 3 parameters. What you need to use is `mapply`, which is meant for functions with multiple parameters. Try, `mapply(pv, c(1000, 1200, 1500, 5600), c(.05, .02, .03, .09), 5)` It appears that the bottom row of the matrix is the present value calculation(not sure why this is).

Comment: Change `for(t in z)` to `for(t in 1:z)` and the `mapply` works perfectly. You will see each periods iteration.

Comment: @small_data88 I understand sapply now, thanks!  I was able to input the vector recieved from my pv function and input it into my inflation function just fine.

Comment: Great! I provided an answer below, but from what it sounds like I was not answering the right question.

Comment: @ small_data88. Maybe I wasn't asking the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
pv = function(fv, d, t)
  fv/(1+d)^t

pv(1.05^2, 0.05, c(1, 2))
```

Here's an explanation. Basically, in R, algebraic functions are applied automatically over numeric data, such that looping is often unnecessary.

Comment: `Vectorize()` does nothing there.  The original function `pv()` was already vectorized.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a change in your for loop, then I used `mapply`:

```
 pv <- function(x,y,z) {
       list2 <- 0
       ans <- 0
       for(t in 1:z){ # changed from t in z
         fv <- x
         d <- y
         rate <- (1+d)^t
         ans[t] <- fv/rate
       }

   return(ans)
 }
```

`mapply(pv, c(1000, 1200, 1500, 5600), c(.05, .02, .03, .09), 5)`

Output:

```
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 952.3810 1176.471 1456.311 5137.615
[2,] 907.0295 1153.403 1413.894 4713.408
[3,] 863.8376 1130.787 1372.712 4324.227
[4,] 822.7025 1108.615 1332.731 3967.181
[5,] 783.5262 1086.877 1293.913 3639.616
```

Each row contains the present value for each value of `x` for a period i.e. row 1 is the present value for 1st period. If you wanted just the 5th period for all values in question:

`mapply(pv, c(1000, 1200, 1500, 5600), c(.05, .02, .03, .09), 5)[5,]`